# Unable to display object array of an object in Angular 2 template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am trying to display an object values in angular 2 templates and specifically when I try to get an object array using ngFor gives me an error saying

**EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./SgDetailComponent class SgDetailComponent - inline template:15:7 caused by: Cannot read property 'tags' of undefined**
I can get string/number property but not object property.

Here's my component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sg-detail',
  templateUrl: './sg-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sg-detail.component.scss', '../../app.component.scss']
})
export class SgDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  errorMessage: string;
  sgDetail: Sg;
  groupId: string;
  ipPermissions: IpPermissions[];
  userIdGroupPairs: UserIdGroupPairs[];
  opPermissionsEgress: IpPermissionsEgress[];
  tags: Tags[];

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private sgService: SgService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      let groupId = params['groupId'];
      this.groupId = groupId;
    });
    this.getSgsByGroupId(this.groupId);
  }
  getSgsByGroupId(groupId: String) {
    this.sgService.getSgByGroupId(groupId)
    .subscribe(
      sgDetail => this.sgDetail = sgDetail,
      error => {
        this.errorMessage = error.getMessage();
        console.error(error.getDescription());
      });
  }
}
```

here's my component.html

```
 <div class="container app_container">
    <ul class="app_list">
        <li *ngIf="sgDetail" class="app_list-item">
            <p>GroupId: {{sgDetail.groupId}}</p>
            <p>GroupName: {{sgDetail.groupName}}</p>
        </li>
        <li *ngFor="let tag of sgDetail.tags" class="app_list-item">
             //this loop sgDetail.tags errors out 
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

and here's my model.ts

```
export interface Sg {
 ownerId: number;
 groupName: string;
 groupId: string;
 description: string;
 ipPermissions: IpPermissions[];
 ipPermissionsEgress: IpPermissionsEgress[];
 vpcId: string;
 tags: Tags[];
}

export interface IpPermissions {
 ipProtocol: string;
 fromPort: number;
 toPort: number;
 userIdGroupPairs: UserIdGroupPairs[];
 ipRanges: Array<number>;
 prefixListIds: Array<number>;
}

export interface UserIdGroupPairs {
 userId: number;
 groupName: string;
 groupId: string;
 vpcId: string;
 vpcPeeringConnectionId: string;
 peeringStatus: string;
}

export interface IpPermissionsEgress {
 ipProtocol: string;
 fromPort: number;
 toPort: number;
 userIdGroupPairs: UserIdGroupPairs[];
 ipRanges: Array<number>;
 prefixListIds: Array<number>;
}

export interface Tags {
 key: string;
 value: string;
}
```

Comment: I think when you use `let sgDetail of sgDetail.tags` you're reassigning `sgDetail`, losing the reference for the property you set on your component. Try using another name, like `let tag of sgDetail.tags`

Comment: @AlexandreAngelim Still doesn't work.I think the error comes while it tries to get tags property .

Comment: I don't see anything wrong there. How about a little debugging? console.log sgDetail just after assigning it on `getSgsByGroupId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by `Asynchorouse call` --> `getSgsByGroupId`, which means the result of`getSgsByGroupId` hasn't come when angular renders the view.

try the safe way angular have provided:

```
<li *ngFor="let tag of sgDetail?.tags" class="app_list-item">
</li>
```

Comment: The error was coming from compile time so when I use sgDetail?.tags it  seems like it skips the hard condition that sgDetails have tags when compiling so doesnt errors out. Still I have to find a solution to this but for now I will accept this answer as a temporary solution and thanks in a million. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
<ul *ngIf="let tag of sgDetail">
  <li>tag.groupId</li>
<ul>

But before looping or using *ngIf you should print sgDetail as a json like this:-
  {{sgDetail | json}}
```