# angular 2 HTTP request json data not displaying without using | JSON

Tags: json, angular, httprequest

Json data not displaying.  I am doing an httpGet and everything seems to be fine.  It seems that data is loaded into my array, and has 3 objects in it.  However nothing displays in HTML, {{associateList}}, or when  I do a "console.log".  I have to do pipe it to JSON {{associateList | JSON}} and then I get everything, of course its all in one chunck.
I cannot seem to be able to access individual objects in the array and I can't seem to figure out what to do.

Here is my GET Service:

```
getAssociatesData(){
    return this.http.get('http://Api/Associates').map(res =>res.json());
```

Here is how I subscribe and other stuff:

```
associateList: associateData[];

this.GetDataServices.getAssociatesData().subscribe(
  associates =>{this.associateList= (associates)},
  error => this.serviceError=error,
      () => {
            this.formatAssociates();
            console.log('associates loaded');
            //this.isLoading.next(false)
          }
  );
formatAssociates(){
  let associateCount = this.associateList.length;
  console.log('number of associates: ' + associateCount);
  this.showAssociates = true;
}
interface associateData{
 id : number;
 firstName : string;
 lastName : string;
 middleName : string;
 fullName : string;
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="showAssociates">
  <span *ngFor="let associate of associateList; let count=index">
    <div id={{count}} >
        associate# = {{count}}
        associateID = {{(associate | async).id}}
        First Name = {{associate.firstName}}
        Last Name = {{associate.lastName}}
        Middle Name = {{associate.middleName}}
        Full Name = {{associate.fullName}}
    </div>
 </span>
</div>

{{associateList | json}}
```

The issue is that I only see data when I pipe "associateList" to json.  I cannot display individual elements.

Comment: How does your JSON look like? Could you post that? :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you have `this.showAssociates = true;` in a method called `formatAssociates()` which is triggered in case of error, so move that to the case of success, after setting the `this.associateList` and you will see those values.

You don't see them cause the variable is probably either undefined or false, so to give a fast try, remove the if condition to prove my theory.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's not it.  It does ouput the field name:  associate# =   associateID =  ....

Comment: well you should give more info about what are you facing, it doesn't help too much your comment. json format, plunkr ...

Answer (score 0):

Does your console show any errors ? I had a similar issue lately and it was due to html rendering was quicker than asynchronous call. Check this link

[Unable to display object array of an object in Angular 2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577795/unable-to-display-object-array-of-an-object-in-angular-2-template)

Comment: I use the "showAssociates" to control the rendering of the HTML after there is something in the array.  Console.log also does not give me the data.  I wonder if the HTTP data I am reading is missing something in the header, but it seems to look just fine when I view it by piping it to JSON.

Comment: @GabrielO If you are getting all data in template while piping it to json then only thing you need to worry is how you are using your ngFor and ngIf. The code looks good to me.  Can you simulate you code in plunker so it will be easy for us to play with your code.

Comment: Haven't used plunker before.  Not sure how it works but I can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you need to execute this service during the `init` life cycle of your angular component.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

//components stuff goes here

export class AssociateComponent implements OnInit {
  associateList: associateData[];
  constructor(getAssociateDataService: getAssociateDataService) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.GetDataServices.getAssociatesData().subscribe(
      associates =>{this.associateList= (associates)},
      error => this.serviceError=error,
      () => {
            this.formatAssociates();
            console.log('associates loaded');
            //this.isLoading.next(false)
          }
    );
  }
  formatAssociates(){
    let associateCount = this.associateList.length;
    console.log('number of associates: ' + associateCount);
    this.showAssociates = true;
  }
  interface associateData{
   id : number;
   firstName : string;
   lastName : string;
   middleName : string;
   fullName : string;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is in the ngOnInit.  Does't make a difference.  The data is loaded into the associateList array and I check the length which shows the exact amount of objects.  I cannot seem to access the individual objects, only see the whole thing when pipe to JSON.